# Using system.currentimemillis to measure how long it takes to calculate the output

Tags: java, time, java.util.scanner

I have a java project to do and the requirements are:

create a loop that repeats the following experiment 10 times. After all 10 iterations are complete, print the average time for one iteration of the experiment:

- Select a random number r from 0 to n.
- Using the System class, note the start time of the experiment
- Repeatedly multiply two 9-digit values in a loop for r iterations. You need not preserve
  the result of this multiplication.
- note the end time of the experiment

---

This is what I have so far:

```
package lee_lab02;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Benchmark {

public Benchmark() {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a value for n:");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {

        Random rand = new Random();
        double r = rand.nextInt(n);
        for(int z=1;z<r;z++)
        {
            long num1 = 145893123;
            long num2 = 901234278;
            long num3 = num1 * num2;
        }
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totTime = end - start;
    long avg = totTime/10;
    System.out.println(avg);
}

}
```

The output of this prompts me with "Please enter a value for n:" but the time is not recorded. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The time is not recorded, or the time is 0?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your program. It is just that you are performing trivial operations in your `for` loop that don't take much time at all. All the iterations are completed in less than 1 millisecond. Just add `Thread.sleep(500);` in your `for` loop and you will see the average getting printed as you expect it.

Also, use `double` for `avg`. (`double avg = totTime/10.0;`).

Answer (score 0):

To perform this kind of benchmarl test, you better need to use `nanoTime()` (remember that 1 000 000ns = 1ms (`currentTimeMillis`)), except if your programm takes more than *10sec* in that case get the time in ms is sufficient (but still possible to use `nanoTime()`) :

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
int nbRound = 10;
for (int i = 1; i <= nbRound; i++) {
   //...
}
long end = System.nanoTime();
long totTime = end - start;
long avg = totTime / nbRound;
System.out.println(avg);
```

I'va also added a variable `nbRound` because it's very quick to make a mistake and write different values in the loop and in the computation of the average, so better use variable when you can

---

And because you program does small things you need to set `n` to a high value, my test :

- `n=100` ==> `105 673ns`
- `n=100000` ==> `1 720 963ns (1.7ms)`

Answer (score 0):

The scan.nextInt() method is a blocking method. So your current thread blocks and the code never moves ahead to execute the remaining lines of code.

You need to change your design a bit to handle this blocking of nextInt() method. You can call the nextInt() method in another thread and remaining logic in another and can control their processing so your average time calculation logic runs.